# How do you style an SSRS Report based on a target style sheet?

Tags: css, styles, ssrs-2008

What I'm wanting to do is embed an SSRS report into a number of existing applications, each of them having their own theme (colours, grid styles, etc.)

What I want to do is design the reports in a way that means that styles are applied based on a target style sheet, instead of generating inline style sections.

The CSS Classes generated by SSRS are in the form a57c, a58, etc. so I can't parse them unfortunately.

I know I can apply a style sheet using the various integration methods in SSRS, however, this only styles the outside of the report, not the report itself.

If it's relevant, I'm using the SOAP API, and SSRS on top of SQL Server 2008, but we'll soon be moving to 2012.

Comment: Martin, if you're happy with answer, please mark it as answered.

Comment: I'm not sure that it covers the use case, so I've not accepted it.  I'm not interested in the answer anymore as I've moved on, but I'll keep track in case there is a reply that meets the requirements

Comment: Fair enough! Although, it could be a long wait...

Answer (score 3):

I have themed dynamic templates that I use for some of my reports. It's fairly complex, but I got all the information I needed from this tutorial and heavily customized it to meet my needs. This gives you the ability to control the look and feel of the reports based on values in a table. It is a 4 part article with source files and such: [dynamic template tutorial](http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/07/17/2-ssrs-reporting-style-based-approach-part-3-reporting-db-delivered/)